# Line breaks (white spaces) are added automatically in SharePoint Designer Workflow Email

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We are upgrading SharePoint 2010 to 2016. When I tested the workflows, I found that in SharePoint Designer Workflow Emails, a line break is added every 1,000 characters, roughly.

For example, the email is set up like this:
[image]

And this is how it looks like in Outlook when I received the email:
[image]

However when I clicked the hyperlink in the email, the link was broken. If you look at the email source, you can see a line break was added into the URL:

[image]

Has you seen this before and do you have a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Lin

Comment: Are you sure that this is related to the 1000 character situation and not your title variable? I would swap it out with a manually input hyperlink just to check and be sure...